# Getting value in loop and replace it in string once in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace, foreach, str-replace

I'm trying to find & replace my values from inside string after getting values from inside loop.
When I replace my string from inside loop then(that method isn't suitable)as it replaces one by one until loop ends and I get a lot of strings with single replacements at each.
I'm trying to replace the whole string with loop values outside only once.
Here's my code.

```
$str = "wi are checking it";   
$langs = array ('w', 'c', 'i');
foreach ($langs as $lang) {
    $search = $lang;  
    $url[] = "<span style='color:red;'>".$search."</span>";
    $qw[] = $search;
}
$op = implode("", $url);
$er = implode("", $qw);
echo $op."<br>";
echo $er."<br>";
$new = str_replace($er, $op, $str);
echo $new;
```

It's output:

[image: Result]

Expected Output:

[[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to do is to use variable names that actually describe what the variable contains. Meaningful variable names. That would make understanding your code a lot easier.

Comment: `$search = $lang;` Why, what does that achieve?

Comment: `$qw[] = $search;` in the loop? So the `$qw` will now look EXACTLY like the `$langs` array ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes actually url[] has the W,C,I in red colors. And $qw[] has them as it is(in default color). I want to replace these red color values with black colored once in the string.

Comment: Its not clear what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: @Lalarukhkhan `c` should also be in red.

Comment: Does your `$langs` always contain single letters? Or can it also contain items with multiple letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non-regex way:**

Make a hashmap of your `lang` characters and loop your string character by character. If the current character is set in the map, add those span tags, else just append the current character.

```
<?php

$str = "we are checking it";   
$langs = array ('w', 'c', 'i');
$lang_map = array_flip($langs);

$new_str = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i){
    if(isset($lang_map[ $str[$i] ])){
        $new_str .= "<span style='color:red;'>".$str[$i]."</span>";
    }else{
        $new_str .= $str[$i];
    }
}

echo $new_str;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/05d0f)

**Regex way:**

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace each character from `lang` surrounded by span tags like below:

```
<?php

$str = "we are checking it";   
$langs = array ('w', 'c', 'i');
$lang_regex = preg_quote(implode("", $langs));

$str = preg_replace("/[$lang_regex]/", "<span style='color:red;'>$0</span>", $str);

echo $str;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/cf47e)

Comment: Isn't the implicit assumption here that `$langs` will always contain single letters?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sure is but I don't wish to speculate unless OP explicitly says so.

Comment: Yes, this should have been mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ohh!! Thanks a lot! This is what I was in fond of :)

Comment: @Lalarukhkhan Glad to help. Can you confirm with the query of KIKO? Will the values in `$langs` be of single letters always?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes values are getting as single. Actually I was splitting my string into single character and was calling it as array. That's why only single character was being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this method.

```
$youText  = "wi are checking it";
$find     = ["wi", "it"];
$replace  = ["we", "its"];
$result   = str_replace($find, $replace, $youText);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Actually this is a correct way of doing. But in the question i wrote the array values. However on real these array values are coming dynamically and that's why I'm calling it by for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace** function :-

```
<?php

$str = "wi are checking it";   
$langs = array ('w', 'i');

$pattern = array();
$htm = array();


for ($i = 0; $i < count($langs) ; $i++) {
    $pattern[$i] = "/".$langs[$i]."/";
    $htm[$i] = "<span style='color:red;'>".$langs[$i]."</span>";
}

$limit = -1;
$count = 0;

$new = preg_replace($pattern, $htm, $str, $limit, $count);

#echo htmlspecialchars($str)."<br>";
echo ($new);
    
?>
```

**Your required Result :-**

```
<span style='color:red;'>w</span><span style='color:red;'>i</span> are checking it
```

Sorry but you can't replace 'c' character because the replacing string also contains 'c' char (i.e. c in `...style = "color:red"`) so this function re-replace this 'c' char and generate a bugged string...

Fix this bug by yourself
For reference [read this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Hi, @techno-gamer Actually I'm trying to get result like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ez-OaKRlgNAoMZo7_m-6pFjaDieMQNYb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: set $limit = -1